# How to Log user activity in frontend and admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, frontend, log, tools

Is there any way to using tools log activity?

Any one have any suggestion how to do this ?

Any tools that helps me to log out for frontend and admin.

Answer (score 0):

Magento EE logs all admin user activity ('Admin Actions Log'):

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/system-operations/admin-actions-log-report.html

For frontend users (customers), Inchoo wrote an article where in they explain to log some customer actions:

http://inchoo.net/magento/logging-user-customer-actions-in-magento/